# Laravel listing multiple errors on reload

Tags: laravel, error-handling

So I have a function which checks a load of jobs and tries to close them. Each job is put into another function which tries to close this job and it returns an array like `return ['error' => 'There are still teams working on job #' . sprintf('%07d', $this->number)];` or `return ['message' => 'Successfully marked job #' . sprintf('%07d', $this->number) . ' as completed"];`

So my question is how do i handle this in my layout so that all success and errors are displayed. This is the function which calls the individual function to close a job:

```
    public function close( Project $project ): RedirectResponse
    {
        try {
            $jobs = $project->jobs()->get();
            $hasErrors = false;

            foreach ( $jobs as $job ) {
                $result = $job->setComplete();
                foreach ( $result as $type => $message ) {
                    if ( $type === 'error' ) $hasErrors = true;
                    Session::flash( $type, $message );
                }
            }
            
            if ( $hasErrors ) {
                Session::flash('error', 'Project still has open Jobs, these will need to be set as complete');
            } else {
                $project->is_enabled = 0;
                $project->save();

                Session::flash('message', 'Project has been closed!');
            }
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Could not close this project! (' . $e->getMessage() . ')');
        }

        return redirect::back();

    }
```

I will omit the $job->setComplete(); function for simplicity, it returns an array with a single row which is either an error or a success message as outlined above.

I have in my layout code which handles validation errors so it would be good if I could use this if possible? If not I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Use $result? I don't get it

Comment: $results =[] before loop and $results[] = $result in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I create an array of the errors and return them as a MessageBag using `withErrors( $errors )` This works using existing layout to handle errors in a property bag.

```
    public function close( Project $project ): RedirectResponse
    {
        $errors =[];
        try {
            $jobs = $project->jobs()->get();
            $hasErrors = false;

            foreach ( $jobs as $job ) {
                $result = $job->getComplete();
                foreach ( $result as $type => $message ) {
                    if ( $type === 'error' ) {
                        $hasErrors = true;
                        $errors[] = $message;
                    } else {
                        Session::flash( $type, $message );
                    }

                }
            }

            if ( $hasErrors ) {
                Session::flash('error', 'Project still has open Jobs, these will need to be set as finished first');
            } else {
                $project->is_enabled = 0;
                $project->save();

                Session::flash('message', 'Project has been closed!');
            }
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Could not close this project! (' . $e->getMessage() . ')');
        }

        return redirect::back()->withErrors( $errors );

    }
```